# Should I close a question which is off-topic but interesting

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I came across this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29486129/2307070 which is (to me at least) off-topic because:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

But I find the question interesting, I even wonder myself about the solution for a few month.

I vote to close but was it the good behavior? Since if the question will be closed, I'll not get the answer...

Comment: question in question looks like [an attempt at Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that fails to meet quality requirements for a valid question over there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is not off topic.

It is requesting **algorithms** to solve the problem. Not existing software tools, not libraries or tutorials. Sure, there is *also* a "if C isn't right for this, what is" patched on to the question, but the essence of the question is about algorithms.

This is absolutely on-topic.

It suffers from other issues that make it close worthy, but being off-topic isn't one of them.

---

But if you **do** find a question that is interesting but off-topic, you **should** close it. Interesting/popular doesn't come into it. If it is off-topic it should be closed.

---

In general - if something looks like it belongs on the site, don't just go closing it off on a technicality.

Comment: That's a fast, nice answer!

Comment: "The question is not off topic" - somewhat disagree, it seems like it's very close to being too broad. OP just dumps a calculation and says "please write an efficient algorithm for me"...